# fetch textarea value (populated by ajax call) in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

My Joomla component makes a jquery call (jquery.post) on button click and populate the result in a textarea.

When I submit the form to the backend, I want to fetch this data present inside the textarea. I tried JRequest::getVar but that does not return the needed content. Neither does $_GET or $_POST. I tried looking for solutions online, but none have been too successful.

Could anyone help me out?

Here's the code:

Fetch content via ajax call

```
jQuery( "#btnGetContent" ).click(function(){

 jQuery("#txtArea").text("");
 var myVar = document.getElementById('var1');
 jQuery.post("https://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&task=ajax_get_content",
        {'myvar' : myVar.value,
        },
        (function(result) { jQuery("#txtArea").val(result); }),
        "html"
        );
   return false;
   });
```

Backend- Try to fetch #txtArea content

...?

Regards,
Abhi

**EDIT 1**

HTML code for txtarea:

```
<textarea style="width:600px;height:70px;" id="txtArea"><?php echo $this->record['recContent']; ?></textarea>
```

Here is the workflow that I desire:

1. When the page loads, it checks if the $record has anything to populate the textarea. If yes, do it. If not, leave it blank.
2. The btn click will send a variable via jquery ajax call and get back content to populate the textarea.
3. When clicked on submit, the form submits. The backend php function needs to get the latest content from textarea and save it to db. .

**SOLUTION
JRequest::getVar('txtArea') works. I forgot to include the name attribute for txtArea in HTML. Thanks jeroen!**

Comment: Can you post the html? Note that at the backend you cannot access the textarea by its ID, only by its `name` attribute.

Comment: +1 for html code. ATM, your ajax POST will give you the following variables server side : com_mycomponent (GET), format (GET), task (GET) and myvar (POST)

Comment: HTML code:

<textarea style="width:600px;height:70px;" id="txtArea"><?php echo $this->record['RecContent']; ?></textarea>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the textarea HTML to this:

```
<textarea name="mycontent" style="width:600px;height:70px;" id="txtArea"><?php echo $this->record['recContent']; ?></textarea>
```

The PHP to retrieve this content on form submission (assuming the form is submitted using POST) would then be:

```
$content = $_POST["mycontent"];
```

Comment: Yep, I just updated the question to include the solution. Was a brainfart for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the textarea content server side, you need to add it to your ajax POST like this :

```
jQuery.post("https://www.domain.com/index.php?option=com_mycomponent&format=raw&task=ajax_get_content", 
            {
                'myvar' : myVar.value,
                'txtarea' :  jQuery("#txtArea").val()
            });
```

The value will be available in `$_POST['txtarea']` (example in PHP)